# Power Alpha Exotic Option with Zero Strike

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Consider a European option on a stock with price $S$ that at expiration at time $T$ pays $S^\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is some arbitrarily chosen power.

Could someone explain how to use stochastic calculus and Ito’s Lemma to derive the formula for the evolution of the function $f=S^\alpha$ in a Black-Scholes risk-neutral world and evaluate the discounted risk-neutral expected value of the payoff. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the Black-Scholes assumptions, under the risk neutral measure $Q$ the stock price follows:

$$dS(t)=S(t)(rdt+\sigma dW(t))$$

Let $X(t)=S(t)^{\alpha}$. Using Ito's lemma

$$dX(t)=\alpha S(t)^{\alpha-1}dS_t+0.5\alpha(\alpha-1)S(t)^{\alpha-2}dS(t)^2$$

i.e.

$$dX(t)=\alpha X(t)(rdt+\sigma dW_t)+0.5\alpha(\alpha-1)\sigma^2X(t)$$

or

$$dX(t)=X(t)((\alpha r+0.5\alpha(\alpha-1)\sigma^2)dt+\sigma dW(t))$$

This is a GBM with a well-known solution

$$X(t)=X(0)e^{\left(\alpha r+0.5\alpha(\alpha-1)^2\sigma^2-0.5\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma dW(t)}$$

Hence because the strike price is zero the price of this option is

$$e^{-rt}E^Q(X(t))=X(0)e^{t(\alpha-1) r+0.5t\alpha(\alpha-1)^2\sigma^2}$$